# Is there a way in OpenVPN to change the VPN server ip or location and this can be done on my system using OPENVPN

Tags: c, linux, openvpn

So I am in need to some info about openVPN that allows to change VPN server Ip or location.

The idea basically is if there is a way to change VPN server location and restart openVPN in my system so the IP gets changed of connecting VPN server so the website will see the updated IP address in my HTTPS request. May some commands that I can use in bash script and run the script from my program so Ip gets updated of VPN server. Is it doable in C and Linux,OpenVPN. if there is any pure C solution then that will be awesome, Is there a way of doing it?

Comment: What I found is there is configuration file ipp.txt I think that can be  used. Is there any command for this? In linux

Comment: Found solution here https://bobcares.com/blog/openvpn-server-change-ip-address/